# Typrom returning SQL Query with conditions for both IsNull and IsNotNull

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm, node.js-typeorm

I am trying to get list of items where deletedAt Column isNotNull but typeorm is returning where condition for deletedAt Column

**Typeorm**

```
    const query = Results.createQueryBuilder('results');
    query.where('results.deletedAt IS NOT NULL');
    query.skip(page * limit);
    query.take(limit);
    console.log(query.getQuery());
    return query.getManyAndCount();
```

it returns **SQL Query** as below

```
SELECT "results"."id" AS "results_id", "results"."date" AS "results_date", "results"."shift" AS "results_shift", "results"."result" AS "results_result", "results"."createdAt" AS "results_createdAt", "results"."updatedAt" AS "results_updatedAt", "results"."deletedAt" AS "results_deletedAt" FROM "results" "results" WHERE ( "results"."deletedAt" IS NOT NULL ) AND ( "results"."deletedAt" IS NULL ) LIMIT 10
```

**Packages**

```
    "typeorm": "^0.3.7"
    "@nestjs/typeorm": "^8.1.4",
    "@nestjs/common": "^8.0.0",
```

Comment: have you tried using `offset` and `limit` instead of `skip`/'take'? see this https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/4742
can you share your entity definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess `results` entity has a `@DeleteDateColumn` in it? If yes, the `IS NULL` part will be automatically applied, plus the one you've entered manually.